# How can I print string as-is in JSP? (The string itself looks like JSP code)

Tags: java, jsp

I just want to print the following string EXACTLY as-is in JSP (it's a tag for an email template, which will later be replaced)

```
<%= escapeUrl(message.delivery.mailParameters.subject) %>
```

I have tried

```
<% out.println("<%= escapeUrl(message.delivery.mailParameters.subject) %>"); %>
```

But this gives me a "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote" error which is weird because there is no open double-quote in the code. Do I need to do anything (like escape a character?)

Comment: May be using a variable will help? Like String st = <%=...%> and <% out.println(st) %>

Comment: @drgPP yeah I tried that... it gives the same error

Comment: You must escape the ```>``` inside the string with a backslash, otherwise the JSP parser sees it as the end of the block and thus complains about the missing end-quote.  The blocks are identified first and only then are they interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, tested in tomcat server. Though it will display error in eclipse IDE, will compile properly and render output

```
<%="<%=escapeUrl(message.delivery.mailParameters.subject)%\>"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The construct you need is called a "static literal" -- you want to bypass the jsp parsing and output the jsp tag directly.  The syntax is as follows:

```
<\%= escapeUrl(message.delivery.mailParameters.subject) %\>
```

ie, add a backslash between the angle bracket and the percent on each end!

As documented under "comments" here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm

Comment: This doesnt work for me... basically I need to print the <% %> exactly as is so that I can pass it as URL parameter as such. `http://www.domain.com?param=<%= escapeUrl(message.delivery.mailParameters.subject) %>`. it doesnt matter that this is not a valid code, i just need to pass this exact string as the <% %> is just a tag that will be replaced later, that happens to look like JSP

Comment: What's processing your jsp?  Jetty?  Tomcat?  Jetty seems to pass the ```%\>``` end tag through to the final output, which IMO is not correct but otherwise it works for me.